# StoryBoard Issue

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.5, uistoryboard

I have an issue that when I press a button to go to another view controller in a storyboard the system says this:

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Authentication2ViewController 0x8d35cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key SignInButton.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c95012 0x10d2e7e 0x1d1dfb1 0xb7ee41 0xb005f8 0xb000e7 0xb2ab58 0x234019 0x10e6663 0x1c9045a 0x232b1c 0xf77e7 0xf7dc8 0xf7ff8 0xf8232 0xf84da 0x10f8e5 0x10f9cb 0x10fc76 0x10fd71 0x11089b 0x110e93 0x110a88 0x46ce63 0x45eb99 0x45ec14 0x10e6705 0x1a2c0 0x1a258 0xdb021 0xdb57f 0xda6e8 0x49cef 0x49f02 0x27d4a 0x19698 0x1bf0df9 0x1bf0ad0 0x1c0abf5 0x1c0a962 0x1c3bbb6 0x1c3af44 0x1c3ae1b 0x1bef7e3 0x1bef668 0x16ffc 0x214d 0x2075 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I don't know how to fix this, can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a button called SignInButton in your storyboard (with that exact spelling)?

Answer (score 0):

You have an outlet in the storyboard established with the name "SignInButton", but the object it is connected to doesn't have a property or instance variable named "SignInButton".

Answer (score 0):

I tried that but it says the same thing, it is because just when I press the button it uses a push action to move another View Controller. I should not say that because it is just a button.